# Allow automatic redirection of the browser using Django and Meraki Captive Portal API

Tags: python, django

I am working with the Meraki Captive Portal API. The flow is like this.

1. Login form containing username and password.
2. I collect the username and password from the form and I POST the details to a login URL provided which handles the authentication.
3. Once authentication is successful, the API redirects the user to a new page. This is done automatically.

Code for login is as below:

```
def index(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        code = request.POST['code']

        login_url = request.session['login_url']
        continue_url = 'http://' + request.get_host() + 
            reverse('splash:home')

        login_params = {"username": username,
                        "password": code,
                        "continue_url": continue_url}

        r = requests.post(login_url, params=login_params)
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        login_url = request.GET['login_url']
        continue_url = request.GET['continue_url']
        ap_name = request.GET['ap_name']
        ap_mac = request.GET['ap_mac']
        ap_tags = request.GET['ap_tags']
        client_ip = request.GET['client_ip']
        client_mac = request.GET['client_mac']

        request.session['login_url'] = login_url
        request.session['continue_url'] = continue_url
        request.session['ap_name'] = ap_name
        request.session['ap_mac'] = ap_mac
        request.session['ap_tags'] = ap_tags
        request.session['client_ip'] = client_ip
        request.session['client_mac'] = client_mac

    return render(request, 'splash/index.html')
```

The problem is here:

```
r = requests.post(login_url, params=login_params, 
        allow_redirects=True)
```

Everything goes fine. However, am not being redirect when the Meraki API does a GET request. Am still at the login page. What can I do to the view to allow the redirect being done by the API.

On the console, I can see the page being called but the browser does not show the home page.

[18/Sep/2018 14:56:20] "GET /splash/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1234

[18/Sep/2018 14:56:20] "POST /splash/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2333

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the error you facing

Comment: Am not getting any error, the problem is that the redirect is not working. Am still on the same login page instead of the home page. The API is the one that does this /splash/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200.

Comment: Where you added `redirect url`?

Comment: can you add `login_url ` view code also

Comment: Mr Singh,  check out the below link. May be am not very clear.

https://create.meraki.io/guides/captive-portal-api/#sign-on-api

Comment: I got this to work by changing continue_url to success_url.....thats all that was needed....